# How to enable debug logs for nginx bitnami image in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, nginx-reverse-proxy, bitnami, nginx-config

I’m using bitnami nginx image on my kubernetes cluster. I want to see the debug logs of nginx.
Does someone know how to enable debug logs in helm chart?
Reference  : https://bitnami.com/stack/nginx/helm

Comment: add a reference to the image

Comment: it appears there is no opportunity for altering the [log level](https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-nginx/blob/1.19.2-debian-10-r10/1.19/debian-10/rootfs/opt/bitnami/nginx/conf/nginx.conf#L5) without writing your own config file (which is possible in helm, just unlikely to be a simple `--set` exercise). Unless you want **every** nginx deployed with debug logging, don't forget that nginx will hot-reload its config file for troubleshooting purposes

Answer (score 0):

There is no configuration available in bitnami helm chart using that you can start debug logs for nginx.

Nothing in `values.yaml`. so just changing configuration via `--set` and debug log won't start.

But you can set Nginx configuration and save logs in a file inside folder and access it.

Comment: I made changes in nginx.conf file 
`error_log         "/opt/bitnami/nginx/logs/error.log" debug;`
And reload nginx via `nginx -s reload` command. But it din't help. Any idea why it din't work?

Comment: @Dipti, if you execute `nginx -V`, you will miss `--with-debug`. That is probably the reason why it is not working. NGINX binaries need to be compiled with that flag: [A debugging log](https://nginx.org/en/docs/debugging_log.html).